# Java Finalization Queue and memory leaks

Tags: java, memory-leaks, finalize, finalization

How to get list of all objects waiting for finalization?, so that I can manually finalize it.

Currently I did not get direct method to get all objects waiting for finalization.

Comment: There is no (legal) way to do it. If your objects aren't getting finalized there may be two reasons for that: 1. GC hasn't been triggered yet 2. You're still holding links to these objects somewhere

Comment: I am not interested, but one search key word would be **phantom reference**.

Comment: Try to find the reason why your objects don't finalize and it should solve your memory leak problem. By calling finalize method explicit you cannot predict when and if the method will be called.

Comment: I don't know if you have memory leaks or you're just trying execute some code when finilizing. To specify what to do just before object is finalized you can override Object.finalize()

Comment: The finalization obects are either from third party libaries or framework like ActiveMQ etc. I dont have control over them, While doing performance analysis in Yourkit I found the object waiting for finalization in terms of 6K to 20K for 20VUSER load. I have trigger Full GC every 20 min and ran System.runFinalization after that, I cant see any improvement. I want explicitly get the list of objects waiting for finalization and release them using object.finalze()

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by using the `ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer()`. A detailed description can be found here: http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue170.html